# Generic type parameter not same type as parameter instance

Tags: c#, generics, domain-driven-design

I have method like this:

```
public static void Raise<TEvent>(TEvent eventToRaise)
    where TEvent : IEvent
{
}
```

And I call that method like this:

```
foreach (IEvent evt in entity.UncommittedEvents)
{
    DomainEvents.Raise(evt);
}
```

where I assume that this is true:

```
bool areSame = typeof(TEvent) == eventToRaise.GetType();
```

but it seems that it is not true. Instead it is:

```
bool areSame = typeof(TEvent) == typeof(IEvent);
```

Why is that so?

Problem here is that I "lost" type of concrete event here. When I pass that type parameter to next method (without instance of event) I have only type "IEvent"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use runtime type definition (`dynamic` type) otherwise generic parameter type will be `IEvent` (inferred from parameter type at compile time):

```
foreach (IEvent evt in entity.UncommittedEvents)
{
    DomainEvents.Raise((dynamic)evt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense, actually.

When you say `DomainEvents.Raise(evt)`, the type of `evt` is known at compile time to be `IEvent`, so the compiler infers the type and writes it for you as `DomainEvents.Raise<IEvent>(evt)`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI ... lazyberezovsky's answer was working solution, but there seems to be a problem that calling code must know to use dynamic cast so I finally ended up solution like this:

```
public static void Raise<TEvent>(TEvent eventToRaise)
    where TEvent : IEvent
{
    if (eventToRaise == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("eventToRaise");
    }

    if (typeof(TEvent) == typeof(IEvent))
    {
        DomainEvents.Raise((dynamic)eventToRaise);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (IDomainEventHandlerProvider provider in DomainEvents.eventHandlerProviders)
        {
            foreach (IEventHandler<TEvent> handler in provider.GetHandlers<TEvent>())
            {
                handler.Handle(eventToRaise);
            }
        }
    }
}
```